# Can I partition by id that already exists on worker?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, partitioning

I am coding a `streaming` fault detection app for several counters, with input: `RDD(Int, BreezeDenseMatrix[Double])`.

For every `RDD`, i want to do some computations and write the `RDD` in a `textfile` in `hdfs` to compare it with the next new `RDD`.

What i want to do is when the new `RDD` has arrived, read the `textfile` and compare them.

The problem is that when i read the `textfile`, i don't know how the `workers` can have the same `id` of the new and the old data in order to compare them.

E.g.

```
Counters = 5
Workers=2
```

If new data are partitioned like:

```
               NewRDD
Worker_1                Worker_2                  
------------------|--------------------
(1, BreezeMatr[]) | (3, BreezeMatr[])
(2, BreezeMatr[]) | (5, BreezeMatr[])
(4, BreezeMatr[]) | 
---------------------------------------
```

I want old data be partitioned like:

```
          `RDD_from_textfile`

Worker_1                     Worker_2                  
----------------------|----------------------
(1, Old_BreezeMatr[]) | (3, Old_BreezeMatr[])
(2, Old_BreezeMatr[]) | (5, Old_BreezeMatr[])
(4, Old_BreezeMatr[]) | 
---------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?